# SQL query to update value based on email address in different table joined by id

Tags: mysql

Please could someone help me construct an SQL query for the following...

I need to update the value 'ucr' in an existing table (db_table_1) with the 'ucr' uploaded to a temporary table (dummy_table) by matching the email address up with the email address that actually exists in a different table altogether (db_table_2).

Both db_table_1 and db_table_2 are joined by id.

db_table_1

```
id     | blah1  | blah2  | ucr
-------+--------+--------+----------
10001  | abc    |   33   |  VALUE1
10002  | def    |   44   |  VALUE2
```

db_table_2

```
id     | blah1  | blah2  | email
-------+--------+--------+----------
10001  | tyu    |   33   |  1@1.com
10002  | fgt    |   44   |  2@2.com
```

dummy_table

```
ucr    | name  | email
-------+-------+------------
10001  | abc   |   1@1.com
10002  | def   |   2@2.com
```

So something like:-

Update 'ucr' in db_table_1 with 'ucr' in dummy_table for 'id' which matches 'email' in db_table_2 in dummy_table. Sorry not sure of the correct syntax when having to join two tables and cross reference another column. Apologies if not explained correctly.

Comment: Please add the desired final result.

Comment: My poor example actually just replaces 10001 and 10002 with 10001 and 10002 but your answer looks good, I am testing it out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution covers your desired result:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (id int, bla1 varchar(10), bla2 varchar(10), ucr varchar(10));
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (10001, 'ABC', 33, 'VALUE1');
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (10002, 'DEF', 44, 'VALUE2');
> CREATE TABLE table2 (id int, bla1 varchar(10), bla2 varchar(10), email varchar(100));
> INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (10001, 'TYU', 33, '1@1.com');
> INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (10002, 'FGT', 44, '2@2.com');
> CREATE TABLE dummy (ucr int, name varchar(100), email varchar(100));
> INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (10001, 'ABC', '1@1.com');
> INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (10002, 'DEF', '2@2.com');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1
> JOIN   table2 
> ON     table1.id = table2.id
> JOIN   dummy
> ON     dummy.email = table2.email
> SET    table1.ucr = dummy.ucr;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM   table1;
> ```
>
> ```
>    id | bla1 | bla2 | ucr  
> ----: | :--- | :--- | :----
> 10001 | ABC  | 33   | 10001
> 10002 | DEF  | 44   | 10002
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=819c5e8cb021b83ce41c1f9575c2a7d6)*

Comment: Excellent, your query did exactly what I was after, thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to help